# how to connect docker mongodb which is in oracle linux virtual machine to mongodb compass

Tags: docker, virtual-machine, docker-container, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, mongodb-compass

I installed mongodb inside docker container in oracle linux virtual machine. I need to connect this mongodb with mongodb compass. I don't have user account for mongodb and don't have mongod config file in the docker or in virtual machine.

## **More Information:**

I created oracle linux virtual machine from oracle cloud. Then, using my current system's(windows) command prompt, I connected to that machine. Through that, I created a docker container inside the virtual machine. And then, I installed mongodb-6.0.2 inside the docker container. Now, when I try to connect this mongodb database(in virtual machine) to the mongodb compass, It is connecting to my current system's mongodb database(which was installed before the creation of this virtual machine).  [I also attached the screenshot of my virtual machine's docker and mongodb's information in cmd.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53lWK.png)

[Here is the screenshot of ip of my docker inside the virtual machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBPJN.png)

Can anyone solve this issue and tell me how can I make connection of this virtual machine database to mongodb compass?

Answer (score 0):

If wanting to use Compass from Windows and connect to a MongoDB container running an Oracle cloud compute instance, you'll need to make sure networking allows for connections to port 27017 via an ingress rule in your [network security group](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Network/Concepts/networksecuritygroups.htm#Network_Security_Groups).

Another option is to use port forwarding over ssh.

Comment: Yes, I added the port 27017 in ingress rule. and tried public ip address as hostname for connecting to mongodb compass but still not connecting

Comment: What was the IP address you used? Also, can you try connecting to MongoDB on the virtual machine over localhost via mongosh? That way you can verify it's not a different network issue. For example: you need to publish the ports via `-p 27017:27017`.

Comment: No, I am unable to change localhost(127.0.0.1). But, with using docker ps on my vm, for my image, under ports it shows "0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp, :::27017->27017/tcp   mongodb " and I used my oracle vm's public IP address.

Comment: But, now I have another issue with oracle cloud infrastructure, when I went to see my VM instances, it shows this message "You don’t have permission to view these resources in this compartment. Try another compartment, or contact your administrator for help." Do you know how to solve this issue